# Cakephp 2, response body content type not working

Tags: php, cakephp, http-headers, httpresponse, cakephp-2.8

```
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->response->header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
$this->response->header("Pragma: public");
$this->response->header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->response->header("Cache-Control: private", false);

//$this->response->header("Content-type: image/png"); //tried also
$this->response->type('jpg');

$this->response->body(readfile($file));

return $this->response;
```

Always returns Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8.

Thanks

Comment: The content type is incorrect, but how about the body itself? Does it contain an image as you expect? Maybe there is another problem in the code and an error response is generated instead. So are there any errors showing? Have you checked the log files?

Comment: No error in the logs.  (temp logs of cakes, apache logs neither)
The image is displayed correctly, if they are inside a page.
However, if I open the image in a new tab (with the same link), due that content type is wrong, the image is not displayed as image but as the ascci (i believe) representation (the classic throw up in scren of binary).

Any ideas? am I missing some step?

Comment: What components are you loading in your controller?

Comment: `use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\Resources;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\File\FileRestProxy;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\File\FileSharedAccessSignatureHelper;

App::uses( 'AuthController', 'Controller' );
App::uses( 'Sanitize', 'Utility' );`

Did you mean that?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried loading the `RequestHandler` component to see if that helps?

Comment: At the end it was the readfile, for some reasons it does not works with the enconding or something.
Changed to file_get_contents  even when it is slower. Maybe later will try to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->response->body(readfile($file));
```

Change this line to

```
$this->response->body(file_get_contents($file));
```

And works.

I know that it is more performant readfile, but at the moment, should work.

Probable something that readfile breaks with the enconding.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I totally missed that. [readfile](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.readfile.php) and [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.file-get-contents.php) work in very different ways :). Only the second one returns the contents of the file while the first one returns an int value!

Answer (score 0):

You can download a file more easily with:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->response->file($path, array('download' => true, 'name' => $name));
```